# error find in Twiiter Api Integration

Tags: android, twitter

I m using twitter api and find the error how to resolve it and i m using lib folder and 4 lib file in this folder but fin in error ..please help me out 
bellow error Notification:

Could not find class 'twitter4j.http.AccessToken', referenced from method com.and.twi.twitter.TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated

```
public void updateLoginStatus() {
        loginStatus.setText("Logged into Twitter : " + TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(prefs));
} // here my apps is crash
```

any one provide me new solution  related to Twiiter Api or new Tutorial link

Answer (score 0):

Put this line in onCreate ::

```
private Twitter twitter;
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
    .setOAuthConsumerKey(Constant.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY)
    .setOAuthConsumerSecret(Constant.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET)
    .setOAuthAccessToken(Constant.twitterToken)
    .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(Constant.twitterTokenSecret);
    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    twitter = tf.getInstance();
```